# How to combine multiple assignment and Range in for loops

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how to (or if it's possible to) combine multiple assignment and ranges in Golang

ex pseudo code of what I'd like to do

```
files := [2]*os.File{}

for i, _, fileName := 0, range os.Args[1:3] {
  files[i], _ = os.Open(fileName)
}
```

The idea being I want to have both an iteration counter (`i`) and the filenames (`fileName`). I know this can be achieved by using the key from range and some math (`key -1`), thats not the point of the example.

**Edit:**

Upon debugging the above example, I learned that `i` will range 0-1 in that example; Because os.Args[1:2] is a slice and that slice has indexing 0-1 .  Therefore I dont need "some math" to properly index the keys.

** EDIT 2: ** 
[This post is also a must read](http://openmymind.net/The-Minimum-You-Need-To-Know-About-Arrays-And-Slices-In-Go/) as to why the above `[2]*os.File{}` is not idiomatic go, instead it should not have a size specified (`files := []*os.File{}`) so that `files` is of type slice of *os.File

Comment: No, this is pretty much done "using the key from range and some math." Do you have a tangible example where that solution would be awkward and you need something else? (Though it's probably still going to be "using the key from range and some math.")

Comment: No, the grammar in the spec is very clear https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements

Comment: @RobNapier I'm just trying to get more proficient at go and working on a contrived example of a file "Weaver" (takes N files and produces an output file that is the first line of each file, then 2nd line of each file . eg file1 = `A\nC\nE`, file2= `B\n,D\n,F`  =>  `A\n\B\n\C\n\D\nE\nF`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of different issues here. First, `range` already does what you want. There's no need for even math.

```
for i, fileName := range os.Args[1:] {
```

`i` will range from 0 to 1 here, just like you want. Ranging over a slice always starts at index 0 (it's relative to the start of the *slice*). (http://play.golang.org/p/qlVM6Y7yPD)

Note that `os.Args[1:2]` is just one element. You probably meant it to be two.

In any case, this is likely what you really meant:

http://play.golang.org/p/G4yfkKrEe7

```
files := make([]*os.File, 0)

for _, fileName := range os.Args[1:] {
    f, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not open file: %v", err)
    }
    files = append(files, f)
}
fmt.Printf("%v\n", files)
```

Fixed-length arrays are very uncommon in Go. Generally you want a slice, created with `make`.

Comment: thanks for helping me learn more idiomatic go, using a slice is definitely the way to go, I added a link to this clarifying blog post: http://openmymind.net/The-Minimum-You-Need-To-Know-About-Arrays-And-Slices-In-Go/

Answer (score 3):

For example,

`so.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    files := [2]*os.File{}
    for i, fileName := range os.Args[1:] {
        if i >= len(files) {
            break
        }
        var err error
        files[i], err = os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(files)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build so.go && ./so no.go so.go to.go
[<nil> 0xc820030020]
$
```